# First list is sorted and the other is unsorted now which is the better approach to merge both list

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, time-complexity

I have one Sorted ArrayList A and one unsorted ArrayList B, now I want to merge items of B in A such that A remains sorted.

Now I can think of only two ways to do this.

> **First one** is to sort Arraylist B and then have two index positions one for Arraylist A and other for Araylist B, then we will move index
>   one by one to insert B list's item in A.

Let us assume size of Arraylist A be `n` and size of Arraylist B be`m`.

Order of complexity will be `O(m Log(m))`(for sorting ArrayList B) + `O(n + m)`.

> **Second Approach** is just have an index on ArrayListaylist B and then use `Binary search` to place item from Arraylist B to A.

Order of complexity will be `O(Log(n) * m)`.

Now can anybody please tell me which approach should i opt, also if you can think of any other approach better than these two then please mention.

Comment: Can you please tell me why are you closing this question ??

Comment: With unknown relationship between n and m it's impossible to say. They are equal in terms of time complexity.

Comment: I think both the below answers gives in some how a right answer. can you please accept one of them if you think so?

Comment: yea sorry I will, give me some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the relative size of `n` and `m`.

When `n > m*log(m)` the run time of the first algorithm with complexity `O(m*Log(m) + max(n,m))`  would be dominated by that linear term on `n` (notice in this scenario `max(n,m)=n` as `n` > `m*log(m)`). In this case the second algorithm with complexity `O(log(n) * m)` would be better.

The exact practical cutoff point would depend on the constant factor for each algorithm particular implementations, but in principle, the second algorithm becomes better as `n` gets bigger in relation to `m`, and eventually becomes the better option. In other words, for every possible value of `m` there exists a big enough value for `n` for which the second algorithm is better.

**EDIT: THE ABOVE IS PARTLY WRONG**

I answered assuming the given complexities for both algorithms, but now I'm not sure the complexity for second one is correct. You propose inserting each number from the unsorted list into the sorted list using binary search, but how  exactly would you do this? If you have a linked list you can not do binary search. If  you have an array you need to displace part of the array on each insert and that is a linear overhead on each insert. I'm not sure if there is a way to achieve this with a more complex data structure, but you can not do this with either a linked list or an array.

To clarify, if you had two algorithms with those time complexities, then my original answer holds, but your second algorithm doesn't have the `O(m log(n))` complexity we assumed.

Comment: Don't you think whatever overhead you think `for the second approach is same as in first approach` because in first approach after sorting i will move index of List B to find where can i put this elemnt but after deciding the position where to put it i will have to move all elements position by 1 in list A, so don't you think it is same for both the approaches.

Comment: The first approach can be implemented with no extra overhead for the insertions either by using extra memory for the output, or if A is implemented as a linked list (O(1) insertion).

Comment: Because suppose I have A(8, 2) and B(1, 3, 9) now acc to first approach when you insert 8, 9 have to shift and for 2, (3, 9, 8) have to move but the result is same for second approach also.

Comment: In your example, if B is a linked list, you don't need to displace all elements after the insertion point, you just rearrange the pointers and the insertion is done in `O(1)`. Alternatively you can place the output in a third list/array C.

Answer (score 1):

> 1st Approach: m * log(n) = O(mlgn)
>
> 2nd Approach: m * log(m) + n + m = O(mlgm)

```
if n <= m {
   1st approach
} else {
   2nd approach
}
```

Comment: In first approach it is `m * Log(n)`.